# SXA checklist filter has an issue with facet values that contain spaces

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

I am trying to create an SXA checklist filter with multiple selections that reads from a list facet.

This facet reads from values that may contain spaces (ex: Action Recommended), however the search results work fine but when I decide to filter using multiple selections the checkbox that contains spaces gets unchecked.

In the below screenshot, they were all checked and once I clicked the "Filter" button, the first value got unchecked eventhough the results are retrieved correctly.

[image]

This doesn't happen if all values in the facet are just one word (without spaces).

I am using SXA 1.8.1 and Sitecore 9.1.1.

Any idea what might be causing this issue or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in SXA versions 1.7.1 to 1.9.0.

Sitecore Support has a hotfix available here: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0757468

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for your quick response. However, I installed the hotfix but the issue still exists, am I missing something?

Comment: I wouldn't know. You would need to take this up with Sitecore Support.